# Can I show some specific post rather than latest post?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, query-posts

I have created a custom post for slider of my theme using owl carousel.As by default, it always shows latest post first in the slider.If I want to show some specific post,what can I do.

Although the posts are in the loop, but is it possible to show,(say no 2, 4, 1, 3 in this order) some specific post rather than latest post?

I am using the slider as shortcode in a custom plugin.

Here is my code ( https://gist.github.com/rashed-amin/47e856dc0823fbcaf5f8338db01e9365)

Thanks

Comment: We can't answer without knowing how you are implementing your CPT with Owl carousel. Please [edit] your question and add some code, so that we can assist you, _the way_ you are.

Comment: You can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/ then in query add this to get the current menu order Include: ‘orderby’ => ‘menu_order’

Comment: You can display random post by setting **orderby** attribute to **rand** in **$args**

Comment: Hi, Thanks, although I want a custom function, but the plugin is now solved the issue.